# 403 Forbidden Error: While running the API request command

Tags: azure, python-requests, azure-functions, azure-api-management

I'm able to update/create the function key using the API as per document.
**https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/web-apps/create-or-update-function-secret**

My main aim is to update the function key every hour so I'm creating a http trigger (with the above api inside it) and scheduling the trigger.

1. For testing purpose I stored the url in one parameter.
   URL:
   'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xyz1/resourceGroups/xyz2/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/func_appname/functions/func_name/keys/poc_testing1?api-version=2021-02-01{"Properties":{"Name": "poc_testing1","Value": "asdsda"}}'

Note: Value here is updating via random gen lib of python

2. Generated a bearer token using the service principal (which I'm already using to connect my stg acc) storing it in auth_token
   header_auth= {'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + auth_token }
3. Now running the below command in python
   import requests
   requests.post(url, headers=header_auth)
   I'm getting 403 forbidden error

I'm thinking that it is not because of the bearer token, Did google the error and it is with the IP address. Can someone help me out here

- I was referring the (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/general/request-throttling-http-403) doc but I'm not using any APIM service

1. Till now I referred the doc from MSFT.
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/web-apps/create-or-update-function-secret
2. I was able to create new function key.
3. I'm trying to do the same using python for which I performed the above steps.
4. Currently ran the above issue steps in my local Visual studio and tried az cli as well but same 403 error.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to update the function key every hour?

If you aim to increased security use AzureAD Auth/OAuth2 rather than the function key.

Regarding the 403 error, please ensure you have assigned proper permissions to the service principal which allow the service principal to modify the azure function.